# Change header content in the same component - Angular 2

Tags: angular

I would like to ask how to change the content of my header for example from Login Text to a Logout after successfully login based on token. My layout structure is I have a Main-Layout.component:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="main-view">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

That has a children component of Home and Login component. The routes is this:

```
path: '',
        component: MainLayoutComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
            { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
        ]
```

The content of  is this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" *ngIf="!isLoggedIn">
                <li><a [routerLink]="['/login']">Log in</a></li>
                <li><a [routerLink]="['/signup']" class="btn btn--red">Sign up</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" *ngIf="isLoggedIn">
                <li><a (click)="logout()">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

    public isLoggedIn: boolean;

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService
    ) {
        this.isLoggedIn = this.authenticationService.isLoggedIn();

    }
```

My problem is when I redirect to home page from login page since the two component is hosted on the same Main-Layout.component the  doesn't render again after redirect so the `this.isLoggedIn = this.authenticationService.isLoggedIn();` on the header.component instructor doesn't read again.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor will be called only once (the isLoggedIn will be assigned a value and stays unchanged after).
To solve the problem, make isLoggedIn a get function instead. eg.

```
public isLoggedIn() {return this.authenticationService.isLoggedIn();}
```

In HTML

```
...*ngIf="!isLoggedIn()"
```

Or just refer the service directly(not good practice?)

```
*ngIf="!authenticationService.isLoggedIn()"
```

Comment: Only explanation is that authenticationService.isLoggedIn() doesn't work as expected. Console log it.

Comment: I console.log that authenticationService.isLoggedIn() before I redirect the page from Login to Home page and it returns true. It kinda weird that when I console.log in the Home component in isLoggedIn() function it return a false.